# Update method is passing id in a weird way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Somehow, my update method after editing is passing the id as "show"

here is a look at the parameters being passed when I "update"\

```
Started PATCH "/owners/show.3328" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-08 12:28:29 +0200
Processing by OwnersController#update as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "owner"=>{"name"=>"Kamal Ghool", "phone"=>"05222123123", "email"=>"kamal057@gmail.com", "notes"=>"", "customer_id"=>"", "phone2"=>"", "address1"=>"Omar ben khattab St", "city"=>"Umm el fahem", "zipcode"=>"30010"}, "commit"=>"עדכון לקוח", "id"=>"show"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Owner Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "owners".* FROM "owners" WHERE "owners"."shop_id" = $1 AND "owners"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["shop_id", 1], ["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Owner with 'id'=show [WHERE "owners"."shop_id" = $1]):
```

My form is, which is the same form for new owner (and works):

```
<%=form_for @owner , remote: true do |f| %>

    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">

        <div>

            <div class="col-md-6" style="float: right">
                <div class="form-group">

        <%#= f.hidden_field :owner_id, { :value => @owner.id } %>

                <%= f.label 'שם לקוח', class:"control-label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label 'טלפון לקוח', class: "control-label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                <%= f.label 'דוא"ל', class:"control-label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label 'הערות ללקוח', class: "control-label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :notes, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label 'ת"ז', class:"control-label" %>
            <%= f.text_field :customer_id, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>     
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label 'טלפון נוסף', class: "control-label" %>
            <%= f.text_field :phone2, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label 'כתובת', class:"control-label" %>
            <%= f.text_field :address1, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>         
      <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <%= f.label 'עיר', class:"control-label" %>
            <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control col-xs2" %>
        </div>  
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <%= f.label 'מיקוד', class:"control-label" %>
              <%= f.text_field :zipcode, class: "form-control col-xs2" %>

     </div>         
     </div>           

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>

                <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
    </div>
```

the update.html.erb renders the same save.js.erb which works find when creating a new Owner.

Comment: Can you add the route definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way of creating RESTful routes in rails is by using resources:

```
resources :owners
```

Which would give you `GET /owners/:id` which is a canonical Rails REST route which points to the show action on `OwnersController`.

Don't create routes such as:

```
/owners/show
/owners/index
/owners/create
```

Unless you want to look incompetent. In Rails the actions are inferred by the HTTP verb used and the presence of a dynamic ID segment on the end.

See:

- [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

Answer (score 0):

3 seconds after posting the question, I found this in my routes file:

```
  get 'owners/show'#, as: :owner
```

and changed it to

```
  get 'owners/show'
```

looks like I did not need that alias.

Comment: That route will not do what you want since it does not have a dynamic id segment. You could declare the route as `get 'owners/:id', to: "owners#show"` but using resources is preferable.